# How are Objective-C 2.0 and C++ exceptions distinguished at runtime?

Tags: objective-c, exception, objective-c++

Consider the following Objective-C 2.0 (or Objective-C++) code:

```m
@try {
   // Do stuff here
}
@catch (id exc) {
   // Handle any Objective-C exception
}
@catch (...) {
   // Handle any non-Objective-C exception (e.g. C++ exception)
}
```

If I remove the first catch block and only keep the second, is there any way the second catch block can tell if it had caught an Objective-C exception or a C++ exception?

**Assumptions**: This is 64 bit code running on Mac OS X 10.10, being compiled with clang. One is allowed to use undocumented or internal facilities, such as `<cxxabi.h>`.

**Motivation**: This may not serve any practical purpose (there is no reason in practice why I can't just use two catch clauses), but I'm trying to understand more about the internals of the Objective-C runtime.

**My research so far**: I see `_OBJC_EHTYPE_id` as a catch typeinfo in the assembly listing, which made me think that I could somehow use `__cxa_current_exception_type()`. However, while that tells me the name of the Objective C or C++ class (by calling `std::type_info::name`), I still can't see how to distinguish Objective-C exceptions from C++ ones. Or else, can I somehow do this using `<unwind.h>`/`<libunwind.h>`?